# iOS 8 after hiding tab bar - reuse this space to display a text box

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6.3

I can hide the tab bar programmatically. The view underneath is a scrollview displaying content. When I scroll up/down I can see the white space at the bottom where the tab bar used to be. My content is not able to use that space.

I want to display a text box in that white space along with some buttons. Any suggestions on how can I do that?

Solution:
Thanks to "SwiftArchitect" advice. I was able to fix this by adding bottom constraints for the ScrollView. Now the scrollview goes till the bottom of the screen.

Comment: In a standard view Controller I added a scroll View and then in viewDidLoad method of the view controller I enabled the Srcoll view as follows:

    myScrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(370, 700);

   [myScrollView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(myScrollView.contentSize.width - 1, myScrollView.contentSize.height - 1, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    
I'm using objective C and in viewDidLoad method of a standard View Controller I made this call to hide the tab bar:

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden=YES;

Yes, I am using auto layout

Comment: I tried to do +1, but it won't let me. Apparently I need 15 reputation points before it would let me +1 the solution.

Comment: (-: I really appreciate. I have posted a link to the ViewLayoutAssistant which is a useful class you should use anywhere you have layout concerns: https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/003be02e89204cad8fea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As often is the case with `AutoLayout`, this question becomes trivial when using `Storyboard` and either the [ViewLayoutAssistant](https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/003be02e89204cad8fea) or an image which will show evidence of resizing.

Let's assume that you are adding 4 constraints for your scroll view:

1. vertical space view.top (0) equal to *Top Layout Guide.bottom*
2. vertical space view.bottom (0) equal to *Bottom Layout Guide.top*
3. and 4. horizontal leading and trailing space

...then when hiding the tabBar:

```
if let tabBarController = self.tabBarController {
    tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = true
}
```

the view.bottom, anchored to the *Bottom Layout Guide.top*, will now stretch all the way to the bottom. If you add a `UILabel` above that line, it will show.

Here is what it would look like in the `Storyboard`:

[image: A storyboard with a navBar and 2 UIViewControllers]

When executed with the [ViewLayoutAssistant](https://gist.github.com/SwiftArchitect/003be02e89204cad8fea), the `UIViewController` that hides the navBar as follow will look like this (*notice that the view now stretches all the way to the bottom since the Bottom.Layout.Guide moved down*):

[image]

Comment: I added constraints so now it goes till the bottom of the screen. When the tab bar is hidden the scrollview takes up that space as well.